# Why local variables do not have default type while global variables have in C?

Tags: c

As far as I know global variables in C have int type as default. I just wonder the rational behind why local (auto) variables has no default type and the code below results compilation error

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    x;
    return x;
}
```

while this does not?

```
x;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    return x;
}
```

Comment: @haccks global variables can be initialized at compile time, so it costs nothing to set them to 0 and that removes some unpredictability. Locals are on the stack, zeroing the stack is not free so thankfully it doesn't happen by default. Or at least I think that's why this was done like this, but don't quote me on that, I dont have a source.

Comment: @haccks Because global initialisation costs nothing, while local initialisation costs runtime overhead.

Comment: @haccks assigning zero into a memory region means clearing. Also you can set your global variable(s) other then zero by changing your c run-time code. Simply crt0.s defines initialization value, not compiler writers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule for the implicit `int` is no longer allowed since c99.

However for local variables (your first example) even this was not allowed as a declaration:

```
x;  /* or even x = 42; */
```

because it was ambiguous. Is this an expression statement that evaluates `x` or a declaration of  `x`? In the file scope statements are not allowed so there is no ambiguity and it can only be a declaration of an `int`.

Comment: You used to be able to write `auto x;` to mean `int x;` (or `auto int x;`) before C99. With C99, as you state, you're no longer allowed to do that.  But you should not be taking liberties like that with modern code and if you are working on ancient code, you should be upgrading it so as to remove the 'implicit `int`' definitions or declarations -- leading towards C99 strict compliance.

Comment: Or `const y = 0;` or even some nice things like `typedef t;`.

Comment: but it still for the implicit function return !

Answer (score 3):

An object name in the global namespace can only mean object declaration/definition. In a local namespace `x;` could also mean "simply do nothing with the already initialised object `x`".